# How to write commands with multiple lines in Dockerfile while preserving the new lines?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to write the following RUN command in the Dockerfile. But, docker is not preserving the new lines.

```
RUN echo "[repo] \
name            = YUM Repository \
baseurl         = https://example.com/packages/ \
enabled         = 1 \
gpgcheck        = 0" > /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
```

I know that `\` at the end of each line escapes the new line. But, is there any way that I can write multiple lines preserving the new line?

Comment: Are you using non *nix platform? Because this works fine for me on Linux.

Comment: @user, I was using Linux.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can use what is called "ANSI-C quoting" with `$'...'`. [It was originally a **ksh93** feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/do-shells-other-than-bash-and-zsh-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string/371873#371873) but it is now available in **bash, zsh, mksh, FreeBSD sh** and in **busybox's ash** (but only when it is compiled with ENABLE_ASH_BASH_COMPAT).

As [RUN uses `/bin/sh` as shell by default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) you are required to switch to something like bash first by using the SHELL instruction.

Start your command with `$'`, end it with `'` and use `\n\` for newlines, like this:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN echo $'[repo] \n\
name            = YUM Repository \n\
baseurl         = https://example.com/packages/ \n\
enabled         = 1 \n\
gpgcheck        = 0' > /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
```

Comment: Is the $ syntax after echo a feature of Dockerfile? Because, I couldn't find about it in the documentation.

Comment: It is bash syntax. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11966402/1395437

Comment: Please, explain what you're doing, don't just drop an opaque solution

Comment: What about `EXPOSE`, or some other command that's not `RUN`? Can you use the `\` notation? I can't find anything only about that because all the examples are with `RUN`.

Comment: A word of caution: the `$' ... \n\ ` technique depends on the shell that docker `RUN` uses being `bash`. On some systems (such as Ubuntu) the shell RUN uses is `/bin/sh` which is often a link to `dash` which is NOT `bash` and does not understand the `$'` syntax.

Comment: as @Anon said, this will NOT WORK if run anywhere else than bash. (doesn't work in `Oh My Zsh` either)

Comment: @Anon well it does work in Alpine linux (currently I am on 3.10.2) which uses shell.

Comment: @suchoss I stand corrected re  `$'...'` only working in `bash` (Alpine uses busybox's `ash` as its default shell). The `$'...'` feature is known as "ANSI-C quoting" but it's not a POSIX shell feature. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371873/109111 it was originally a `ksh93` feature but it is now available in `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, FreeBSD `sh` and in busybox's `ash` (but only when it is compiled with `ENABLE_ASH_BASH_COMPAT`). It is NOT available in `dash` which is Ubuntu's default `/bin/sh`.

Comment: It doesn't work with variables.

Comment: If I need to use an environment variable in the script and pass the value at run time. How to do it?

Comment: I think `RUN` command can be executed as `RUN /bin/bash -c $'echo ...` , without using `SHELL` which affects the shell for subsequent docker commands as well.

Answer (score 97):

Use `printf` to allow a single RUN command to output multiple lines of text, using `\n` to insert newlines.

Executing:

```bash
RUN printf 'example\ntext\nhere' >> example.txt
```

appends:

```
example
text
here
```

to the file `example.txt`

Comment: This worked for me! Echo had newline characters in the file as "\n" instead of an actual new line.

Answer (score 42):

You can use:

```
RUN echo -e "\
[repo] \n\
name            = YUM Repository \n\
baseurl         = https://example.com/packages/ \n\
enabled         = 1 \n\
gpgcheck        = 0\
" > /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
```

This way you will have a quick way to check what the file contents are. You just need to be aware that you need to end every line with `\` and insert the `\n` when needed.

Comment: This requires `echo -e` to interpret `\n`

Comment: Using the `-e` option gave me an unexpected behaviour. The option is not interpreted as such but as part of the text to be printed.

Comment: Good solution. Interestingly, if the first line after `RUN echo -e ...` is *#!/bin/bash \n\* it doesn't end up in the file. Fixed it by doing `echo -e '#!/bin/bash \n\`  instead. And I'm using `'` instead of `"` to avoid parameter expansion. Apologies for the formatting, not working as expected!

Answer (score 26):

I ended up using a combination of the examples listed here since the new line `\n` did not work with `echo`.

```bash
RUN printf 'example \n\
text \n\
here' >> example.txt
```

It produces the following, as expected:

```
example
text
here
```

Comment: How is your answer differs from CTodea's one?

Comment: @TheGodfather That's a multiline example. Better answers the original question too.

Answer (score 22):

As of Docker 18.09 and [Dockerfile syntax 1.4](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#syntax),
Dockerfiles support heredocs (ie what you're looking for here) natively!

1. [Enable BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/), eg by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`.
2. Add this line to the top of your Dockerfile:

   ```
   # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
   ```

   or as recommended in the documentation

   ```
   # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   ```
3. Rewrite your heredoc like so:

   ```
   COPY <<EOF /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
   [repo]
   name            = YUM Repository
   baseurl         = https://example.com/packages/
   enabled         = 1
   gpgcheck        = 0
   EOF
   ```

You can also use this to run multiple bash commands in a single `RUN` block, etc. More details: [Docker blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/), [Dockerfile syntax docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#here-documents).

Comment: In the blog of Docker, the line is `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs`.

Comment: What is your example doing? Is it writing to a file named `/etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz` ? I tried that syntax and it does not create a file

Comment: @red888 hmm! Yes, that's what it's doing, same as OP's. Not sure why these steps aren't working for you, they are for me.

Answer (score 5):

May be it's help you ( https://github.com/jen-soft/pydocker )

[ Dockerfile.py ]

```py
from pydocker import DockerFile  # sudo pip install -U pydocker

d = DockerFile(base_img='debian:8.2', name='jen-soft/custom-debian:8.2')

d.RUN_bash_script('/opt/set_repo.sh', r'''
cat >/etc/apt/sources.list <<EOL
deb     http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
EOL
apt-get clean && apt-get update
''')

d.EXPOSE = 80
d.WORKDIR = '/opt'
d.CMD = ["python", "--version"]

# d.generate_files()
d.build_img()
```

```sh
# sudo wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

python Dockerfile.py
docker images
```

Answer (score -5):

You can execute RUN several times to complete your file:

```
RUN echo "[repo]" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
RUN echo "name            = YUM Repository" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
RUN echo "baseurl         = https://example.com/packages/" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
RUN echo "enabled         = 1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
RUN echo "gpgcheck        = 0" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/Repo.repoxyz
```

This may not be the optimal solution because it creates a new layer for every RUN command. Still, every layer will be as big as the change you make, which in this case it's in the order of Bytes (first RUN layer should be 7-byte).

The benefit of this solution is that it will work with all shells.

Comment: Probably better to concat these commands with `&&` for better caching purposes, reduced logging and faster `Dockerfile` build times

Comment: This solution adds too many layer to your image which will increase your build time.