# docker run long multi-line commands on Windows Host

Tags: go, docker

Is it possible to run a multi-line command from Dos on Windows, trying to not create a `Dockerfile` for this sample.

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$GOPATH":/go -w /go/src/github.com/iron-io/ironcli golang:1.4.2-cross sh -c '
for GOOS in darwin linux windows; do
  for GOARCH in 386 amd64; do
    echo "Building $GOOS-$GOARCH"
    export GOOS=$GOOS
    export GOARCH=$GOARCH
    go build -o bin/ironcli-$GOOS-$GOARCH
  done
done
'
```

I see lots of people using this cross compiler for Go Language

Comment: This has more to do with how arguments are parsed on the command line than docker or go. Apparently the [`^` character can be used to escape newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/windows-how-to-specify-multiline-command-on-command-prompt). You can also reformat that shell script to fit on a single line by using `;` in place of newlines except after the `do` keyword.

Comment: Do you think this is the simplest way to type the command? Or you just want to know how to multiline command on `cmd` propmpt?

Comment: If this is something you'll be using often, why not create a new image from the one you're using, copy your command into a script file and copy the script file into the image?

I.e.
FROM golang:1.4.2-cross
COPY buildscript.sh

ENTRYPOINT ['buildscript.sh']

Comment: I ended up install Cygwin and using the bash shell to get this to work. Thank you for the suggestion of just putting the shell script on the Image, I was also looking at going that route.

Comment: [How to write commands with multiple lines in Dockerfile while preserving the new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33439230/6521116)