# How to write commands with multiple lines in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This command does not run correctly. give error to execute them

How to write commands with multiple lines in Dockerfile

```
RUN echo <VirtualHost *> >>  phabricator.conf && \
    echo <Directory "/var/www/html/repository/phabricator/webroot/">' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks' >>phabricator.conf && \
    echo Order allow,deny' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo Allow from all' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo Require all granted' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo </Directory>' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo ServerName localhost' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo DocumentRoot /var/www/html/repository/phabricator/webroot' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo  >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo RewriteEngine on' >>  phabricator.conf && \
    echo RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)-[L,QSA]  >>  phabricator.conf && \
    echo RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico -[L,QSA]   >>  phabricator.conf && \
    echo RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA] >>  phabricator.conf && \
    echo '</VirtualHost>' >> phabricator.conf && \
    echo '' >> phabricator.conf && \
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write commands with multiple lines in Dockerfile while preserving the new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439230/how-to-write-commands-with-multiple-lines-in-dockerfile-while-preserving-the-new)

Comment: And the error you're seeing is...?

Answer (score 3):

1. The last line should not end with `&& \` - not sure if it is *the* problem but it sure is *a* problem.
2. This is a terrible practice. As you can already see, its hard to debug. Create your files normally, and just `COPY` them to the image instead of creating them with an awkward chain of shell commands.

Comment: To have less intermediate images it is better to have less `RUN` steps. 
But @DannyB is right, for copy files please use `COPY`.